# Extract parent and child node from python tree representation

Tags: python, tree, extract, nltk

```
[Tree('ROOT', [Tree('S', [Tree('INTJ', [Tree('UH', ['Hello'])]), Tree(',', [',']), Tree('NP', [Tree('PRP$', ['My']), Tree('NN', ['name'])]), Tree('VP', [Tree('VBZ', ['is']), Tree('ADJP', [Tree('JJ', ['Melroy'])])]), Tree('.', ['.'])])]), Tree('ROOT', [Tree('SBARQ', [Tree('WHNP', [Tree('WP', ['What'])]), Tree('SQ', [Tree('VBZ', ['is']), Tree('NP', [Tree('PRP$', ['your']), Tree('NN', ['name'])])]), Tree('.', ['?'])])])]
```

I have many of these strings available in Python, which are actually tree representations. I want to extract the parent and child node for every word, e.g. for `'Hello'` I want `(INTJ, UH)`, and for `'My'` it is `(NP, PRP$)`.

This is the outcome I want:

```
(INTJ, UH) , (NP, PRP$), (NP, NN) , (VP, VBZ) , (VP , VPZ) , (ADJP, JJ) , (WHNP, WP), (SQ, VBZ), (NP, PRP$), (NP, NN)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Your data structure is `sentences`, then. If you don't understand how to get from there to the ability to use the solution in my answer, you'll need to ask a new question.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29397460/extract-parent-and-child-node-from-python-tree) new question asked.Thank You very much for helping me out @Zero

Comment: @rombi That is good, however do remove parts of the new question from here! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is obviously the representation of a list of `Tree` objects. It would be much better if you had access to, or could reconstruct in some other way, that list – if not, the most straightforward way to create a data structure you can work with is [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) (with all the [usual caveats](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) about calling `eval()` on user-supplied data).

Since you don't say anything about your `Tree` class, I'll write a simple one that suffices for the purposes of this question:

```
class Tree:

    def __init__(self, name, branches):
        self.name = name
        self.branches = branches
```

Now we can recreate your data structure:

```
data = eval("""[Tree('ROOT', [Tree('S', [Tree('INTJ', [Tree('UH', ['Hello'])]), Tree(',', [',']), Tree('NP', [Tree('PRP$', ['My']), Tree('NN', ['name'])]), Tree('VP', [Tree('VBZ', ['is']), Tree('ADJP', [Tree('JJ', ['Melroy'])])]), Tree('.', ['.'])])]), Tree('ROOT', [Tree('SBARQ', [Tree('WHNP', [Tree('WP', ['What'])]), Tree('SQ', [Tree('VBZ', ['is']), Tree('NP', [Tree('PRP$', ['your']), Tree('NN', ['name'])])]), Tree('.', ['?'])])])]""")
```

Once we have that, we can write a function that produces the list of 2-tuples you want:

```
def tails(items, path=()):
    for item in items:
        if isinstance(item, Tree):
            if item.name in {".", ","}:  # ignore punctuation
                continue
            for result in tails(item.branches, path + (item.name,)):
                yield result
        else:
            yield path[-2:]
```

This function descends recursively into the tree, yielding the last two `Tree` names each time it hits an appropriate leaf node.

Example use:

```
>>> list(tails(data))
[('INTJ', 'UH'), ('NP', 'PRP$'), ('NP', 'NN'), ('VP', 'VBZ'), ('ADJP', 'JJ'), ('WHNP', 'WP'), ('SQ', 'VBZ'), ('NP', 'PRP$'), ('NP', 'NN')]
```

Comment: There is error coming in line 6 of tails function. I think  keyword `from` is not required.
Secondly when i am running the code **print list(tails(data))**,it gives me this  `[<generator object tails at 0x043CA918>, <generator object tails at 0x043CA940>] `. Please help me out.

Comment: Ah, you're using a version of Python less than 3.3, then. Let me update the code ...

Comment: @rombi I've updated the code so it no longer relies on the `yield from` construct [introduced](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380-syntax-for-delegating-to-a-subgenerator) in Python 3.3 ­– hopefully it works for you now.

Comment: i am using eval on a string which is very large. I am getting this error. `s_push: parser stack overflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stanford.py", line 146, in <module>
    main()
  File "stanford.py", line 143, in main
    get_file()
  File "stanford.py", line 55, in get_file
    data = eval(str(val))` .Any workaround to rectify this error @Zero

Comment: From my answer: **"It would be much better if you had access to, or could reconstruct in some other way, that list"**. Using `eval()` is a last resort (and I only used it because you didn't supply a data structure in your question); since that string is the representation of an existing data structure, you should be using that data structure instead. Calling `eval()` on a representation complex enough to give you a stack overflow error is obviously a terrible idea.

Comment: See my edited question.Maybe this can be of help.@Zero